# React Native Quiz app adding voiceover functionality

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech, voiceover

How to implement offline voiceover functionality in a React Native app?

I am developing a quiz app using React Native, and I want to add voiceover functionality to the passages displayed before each question. The app is designed to work offline, so I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on an internet connection.

I have limited experience with React Native development and I'm unsure about where to start with implementing voiceover. Should I use a Text-to-Speech (TTS) library or is there a way to incorporate pre-recorded voice clips?

Specifically, I would like to know:

1 What are the recommended libraries or techniques for implementing offline voiceover in a React Native app?

2 How can I convert text passages to audio clips in an offline environment?

3 How do I integrate the voiceover functionality into my React Native components and trigger the audio playback when a passage is displayed?

I appreciate any guidance, code snippets, or resources that can help me get started with adding voiceover functionality to my React Native quiz app

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement your own screen reader. Both iOS (VoiceOver) and Android (Talkback) have built-in screen readers. You just have to code your app properly so that they'll work. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility